# Could GraphQL be useful for a system without a frontend client?

Tags: api, reactjs, architecture, microservices, graphql

So far all the guides i have looked at involve communicating with a frontend client via Graphql, I wonder does it have any usage for something purely backend, such as communicating among microservices?

Comment: Sure, it is perfectly possible to use it. The savings and the contract works the same whether on front-to-backend or backend-to-backend. Other possibilities exist more minded on backend though. Check out gRPC for a super fast protocol and framework specifically for backend-to-backend comms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly make a request to the API from another server as well. Just as you can make a call to any REST endpoint from anywhere, you can perform server to server communication with GraphQL APIs as well.

For example, at [Scaphold](https://scaphold.io), we use Lambda for many webhooks and scheduled tasks. And from our microservice, we use the [`request` library](https://github.com/request/request) to make POST requests to the Scaphold server's GraphQL API.

[Here's an example of a create mutation that you can use from a Node server.](https://docs.scaphold.io/coredata/mutations/#create)

Hope this helps!